# Finding an irregularly shaped image inside a larger image

Tags: c#, image-recognition

I have this images:

- Case 1

[image: Case 1]

- Case 2

[image: Case 2]

- Case 3

[image: Case 3]

I have tried to extract the puzzle from the image so I can compare it.. it's something like this:

[image]

What I want is to be able to found an irregular shaped image (in this case, the puzzle) inside a larger image. Is this even possible to do?

****EDIT

I'm using this algorithm to compare the bitmaps:

```
private Rectangle searchBitmap(Bitmap smallBmp, Bitmap bigBmp, double tolerance)
{
    BitmapData smallData =
      smallBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, smallBmp.Width, smallBmp.Height),
               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
               System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData bigData =
      bigBmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bigBmp.Width, bigBmp.Height),
               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
               System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    int smallStride = smallData.Stride;
    int bigStride = bigData.Stride;

    int bigWidth = bigBmp.Width;
    int bigHeight = bigBmp.Height - smallBmp.Height + 1;
    int smallWidth = smallBmp.Width * 3;
    int smallHeight = smallBmp.Height;

    Rectangle location = Rectangle.Empty;
    int margin = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 * tolerance);

    unsafe
    {
        byte* pSmall = (byte*)(void*)smallData.Scan0;
        byte* pBig = (byte*)(void*)bigData.Scan0;

        int smallOffset = smallStride - smallBmp.Width * 3;
        int bigOffset = bigStride - bigBmp.Width * 3;

        bool matchFound = true;

        for (int y = 0; y < bigHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bigWidth; x++)
            {
                byte* pBigBackup = pBig;
                byte* pSmallBackup = pSmall;

                //Look for the small picture.
                for (int i = 0; i < smallHeight; i++)
                {
                    int j = 0;
                    matchFound = true;
                    for (j = 0; j < smallWidth; j++)
                    {
                        //With tolerance: pSmall value should be between margins.
                        int inf = pBig[0] - margin;
                        int sup = pBig[0] + margin;
                        if (sup < pSmall[0] || inf > pSmall[0])
                        {
                            matchFound = false;
                            break;
                        }

                        pBig++;
                        pSmall++;
                    }

                    if (!matchFound) break;

                    //We restore the pointers.
                    pSmall = pSmallBackup;
                    pBig = pBigBackup;

                    //Next rows of the small and big pictures.
                    pSmall += smallStride * (1 + i);
                    pBig += bigStride * (1 + i);
                }

                //If match found, we return.
                if (matchFound)
                {
                    location.X = x;
                    location.Y = y;
                    location.Width = smallBmp.Width;
                    location.Height = smallBmp.Height;
                    break;
                }
                //If no match found, we restore the pointers and continue.
                else
                {
                    pBig = pBigBackup;
                    pSmall = pSmallBackup;
                    pBig += 3;
                }
            }

            if (matchFound) break;

            pBig += bigOffset;
        }
    }

    bigBmp.UnlockBits(bigData);
    smallBmp.UnlockBits(smallData);

    return location;
}
```

Credits to [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38619/Finding-a-Bitmap-contained-inside-another-Bitmap)

Comment: @jsotola as you can see the image I seek may be anywhere overlapping any image... if you look only for the puzze image in those cases you will notice that they have different backgrounds...colors...etc. I need to found the puzzle image (or any part of it). the background and color part is just a reason to ignore these items when trying to compare pixels

Comment: @jsotola YES! the puzzle "shape". How can I found the shape inside another image??

Comment: That algorithm is not appropriate for a pattern recognition. You need this: [Edge Based Template Matching](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99457/Edge-Based-Template-Matching) or this: [Contour Analysis for Image Recognition](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C)

Comment: please edit your question to make it clearer ... you are asking about `finding an irregularly shaped image inside a larger image`

Comment: done @jsotola... edited the whole question

Comment: @Jimi I guess I would have to do my own implementation of those algorithm, right? Is there any simpler approach?

Comment: The algorithms are already implemented and source code is available, in the sample projects. The first is simpler, used for fixed patterns. The second one is more complex, it can detect a pattern when a rotation is applied. These are both *blueprints*, something you can build on. Production code goes much deeper than that.